# Equation with derivative on the left side

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation with derivative on the left side:

$y'=x^2e^x$

My theory is, that the solution to this equation is a simple integral $\int x^2 e^x dx$.

Is my theory correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. As a basic rule, notice that y is a function of x, y(x), and the problem says the derivative of y(x) is $x^2e^x$, which only depends on x, not y. So you only need to do an antiderivative.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. You only have to calculate the antiderivative of the RHS